# Create scoped relationship with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relationship

I have two models in Rails:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum user_type: [:admin, :normal] 
end
```

and

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Inclusive I wrote the following Rspec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
    it { should belong_to(:department).conditions(user_type: :admin)}
end
```

What I need and I dont know how, is to implement this. How can I create relationship between two models based on their type?

in other words, how can make this relation only with users with type "admin"?

The link or similar questions I saw, does not work for me, the test still fail

Comment: Or if `user_type` is `normal` then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *scope* like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum user_type: [:admin, :normal]
  belongs_to :department, -> { joins(:users).where("users.user_type = ?", 0) }
end
```

[*Associations* are built from `Relations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), and you can use the `Relation` syntax to customise them. Inside the `-> { ... }` block you can use all of the usual `Relation` methods.

Comment: hi @Arup,

I found a problem... Defining this way, my test passes... but there are a error: it is trying to build the select like this: `SELECT  "departments".* FROM "departments" WHERE "departments"."id" = $1 AND "departments"."user_type" = 'admin' LIMIT 1`

Comment: note that `user_type` column exists only on USer table and not on Department table

Comment: doent work. `SELECT  "departments".* FROM "departments" WHERE "departments"."id" = $1 AND (users.user_type = 'admin') LIMIT 1`

Comment: what's the column datatype of `user_type` ?

Comment: user_type is integer.

Comment: @P.Santos did you try `{ where "users.user_type = ?", 0 }`?